# Looking to take only main folder name within a tarball & match it to folders to see if it's been extracted

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I have a situation where I need to keep .tgz files & if they've been extracted, remove the extracted directory & contents.

In all examples, the only top-level directory within the tarball has a different name than the tarball itself:

```
[host1]$ find / -name "*\@*.tgz"  #(has an @ symbol somewhere in the name)
/1-@-test.tgz
[host1]$ tar -tzvf /1-@-test.tgz | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $6 }'
TJ  #(directory name)
```

What I'd like to accomplish (pulling my hair out; rusty scripting fingers), is to look at each tarball, see if the corresponding directory name (like above) exists.  If it does, `echo "rm -rf /directoryname"` into an output file for review.

I can read all of the tarballs into an array ... but how to check the directories?

Frustrated & appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
find / -name "*@*.tgz" | while read line; do
    dir=$(tar ztf "$line" | awk -F/ '{print $6; exit}')
    test -d "$dir" && echo "rm -fr '$dir'"
done
```

Explanation:

- We iterate over the `*@*.tgz` files found with a `while` loop, line by line
- Get the list of files in the `tgz` file with `tar ztf "$line"`
- Since paths are separated by `/`, use that as the separator in the `awk`, print the 6th field. After the print we exit, making this equivalent to but more efficient than using `head -n1` first
- With `dir=$(...)` we put the entire output of the `tar..awk` chain, thus the 6th field of the first file in the tar, into the variable `dir`
- We check if such directory exists, if yes then `echo` an `rm` command so you can review and execute later if looks good

My original answer used a `find ... -exec` but I think that's not so good in this particular case:

```
find / -name "*@*.tgz" -exec \
  sh -c 'dir=$(tar ztf "{}" | awk -F/ "{print \$6; exit}");\
  test -d "$dir" && echo "rm -fr \"$dir\""' \;
```

It's not so good because of running `sh` for every file, and since we are using `{}` in the subshell, we lose the usual benefits of a typical `find ... -exec` where special characters in `{}` are correctly handled.

Comment: @user3151983 crap. `z.tar` was a copy-paste error, fixed it now.

Comment: No, {} can't be empty there. Why do you think that? What error message do you get?

Comment: @TJO my solution *should have* worked, but I rewrote my answer with a better way. I added detailed explanation so that you understand the meaning of every step, and if you need to make adjustments (if I misunderstood your problem), then perhaps you'll be able to fix yourself.